# Subir fichero a wordpress con plugin

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-plugin

Quisiera saber como puedo subir un fichero JSON mediante la función wp_upload_handle().

Esto lo quiero hacer la Setting API. Pongo el código por si alguien me puede ayudar.
Gracias!!

```php
    function handle_file_upload($option)
    {
        if(!function_exists('wp_handle_upload'))
        {

            require_once(ABSPATH .'wp-admin/includes/file.php');
        }

        if(!empty($_FILES["json-file"]["json_name"]))
        {

            echo "Fichero";
            $movefile = wp_handle_upload($_FILES["json-file"], array('test_form' => FALSE));

            if ( $movefile && ! isset( $movefile['error'] ) ) {
                echo "File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.\n";
                var_dump( $movefile );
            } else {
                /**
                * Error generated by _wp_handle_upload()
                * @see _wp_handle_upload() in wp-admin/includes/file.php
                */
                echo $movefile['error'];
            }

            $temp = $movefile["url"];

            return $temp;   
      }

      return $option;
    }
```

El caso es que con imágenes va bien, pero si subo un fichero json no lo sube...

Gracias por todo.
Saludos.

Comment: Has comprobado el fichero "wp-admin/includes/file.php"? Lo mismo hay restricciones de formatos.

Comment: Pues no... no lo he comprobado.... Desconocía esto... Se pueden modificar estas restricciones desde alguna función propia de WordPress? He visto que existe la api Filesystem pero no se como funciona....

Comment: No estoy seguro. Lo que si es claro es que algo te está bloqueando la subida del json. Por tanto, viendo tu código y que incluyes el archivo file.php me quiere sonar que debe tener algún tipo de filtro ahí.

Comment: Gracias! Seguiré investigando a ver....